# NSColorWell color property is nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iboutlet, nscolor, nscolorwell

I am trying to set the color of an `NSView`'s layer to the color of an `NSColorWell`. Please consider my code:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    self.layer.backgroundColor = self.colorWell.color.CGColor;

    NSLog(@"%@",self.colorWell.color.CGColor);
}
```

`colorWell` is declared as an `IBOutlet` and I have assured it is connected in Interface Builder. I noticed the color wasn't changing on `mouseDown:`, so I added the `NSLog()` line to log the color coming in from the `NSColorWell`. I get: `(null)` in the console. I'm not sure what could be going wrong with such a seemingly simple task. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
I have logged the value of the colorWell itself and the result is `(null)`. Why can I clearly see it as connected in Interface Builder? Also, when I moved the IBOutlet from my NSView subclass to the AppDelegate and added a different connection, I do not get a null value.

Comment: Unplug the outlet, blow out the dust, then plug it back in.

Comment: did you set the color well to a color? is that sending a correct value?

Comment: @Volker The color well's color property is set when the well is clicked on. The color well is in Interface Builder. I have a custom view with an IBOulet that connects to said well in Interface Builder. The Color Well has a null value like this. Interestingly enough, when I do the exact same thing, but put the IBOutlet in my App Delegate, I the color well is no longer null.

Comment: How do you create the custom view? In IB or in code?